# What are install* eula* and hash code directories sitting on the root of my drive?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I get these all of the time. I am guessing they are Windows Update, but why they are writing to the root of my secondary hard drive I do not know. The partition is not marked as a system partition. Any idea what these are and how to get rid of them permanently?

```
 Directory of E:\

11/19/2009  09:57 PM    <DIR>          37d32bf0bb1d8cfe965e970f000a609d
11/19/2009  06:10 PM    <DIR>          ac8cc0e29dcc41086f66989ebd
11/07/2007  08:00 AM            17,734 eula.1028.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM            17,734 eula.1031.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM            10,134 eula.1033.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM            17,734 eula.1036.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM            17,734 eula.1040.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM               118 eula.1041.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM            17,734 eula.1042.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM            17,734 eula.2052.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM            17,734 eula.3082.txt
11/07/2007  08:00 AM             1,110 globdata.ini
11/07/2007  08:44 AM           855,040 install.exe
11/07/2007  08:00 AM               843 install.ini
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            75,280 install.res.1028.dll
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            95,248 install.res.1031.dll
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            90,128 install.res.1033.dll
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            96,272 install.res.1036.dll
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            94,224 install.res.1040.dll
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            80,400 install.res.1041.dll
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            78,864 install.res.1042.dll
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            74,768 install.res.2052.dll
11/07/2007  08:44 AM            95,248 install.res.3082.dll
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those are from the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable package. That's a little mistake on Microsoft's part, they were supposed to be written to the temp directory on the C drive, but instead they end up being written to the root of whichever drive has more free space. They can be deleted.

Microsoft has a knowledge base article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950683